# Solutions for filtering dynamic IP addresses in Google Analytics?

Tags: seo, google-analytics, google-search-console

Without a static IP address from your ISP, what solutions are people using to filter their own web traffic through Google Analytics to help improve the accuracy of the data?

I get the reasoning and the process for setting up the filter based on IP address, but since my ISP may or may not change my IP at any time, at some point that filter becomes ineffective and I've got to go reset it, correct?  Is there a better solution?

Comment: I've been doing some more research since posting the question and it looks like there's a few solutions.  I'd still love any suggestions or comments from someone who's gone through it.

I'm in the process of using this one...

http://stackoverflow.com/a/23914331/3157968

Comment: Is there an option to filter by domain name?

Comment: Personally, on the client side I use an addon for Firefox that allows me to send a custom HTTP header on each HTTP request and on the server side I check if the that custom header exist and if it has a specific value. If it does I don't output the Google Analytics code else I do. You can achieve the exact same thing by using a secret cookie in your browser but if you accidentally delete the cookies in your browser you will have to remember to set it again.

Answer (score 1):

Once your website becomes popular this isn't an issue.  My own pageviews are 0.0001% of my traffic on my popular websites.   I just don't worry about it.  Private browsing, bad bots, and referral blockers cause me far more analytics headaches than my own traffic does.

A solution that I considered on a smaller site is suppressing the Analytics snippet when I'm logged into my website.  I don't often view much of me website without being logged into it so that I can administer it.

Comment: I get that on the traffic volune piece, but Im small-time... working with a lot of small, local businesses where gobs of nationwide or global traffic isn't realistic or needed. I'm playing with the cookie solution now via a browser add-on and an if/else on the GA script.  It works fine on my side and I just need to be aware of if I'm clearing the browser. It doesn't account for the customer visiting their own site, especially at launch when everyone's excited about the new site.

Comment: You could also just use use AdBlock+ yourself.   Just add a rule that blocks Google Analytics.